# How to sort by extension instead of type in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11

I use Google Chrome to open svg and pdf files but Windows Explorer sorts them as the same type:

[image]

Can I somehow sort by extension instead? (`.svg`, `.pdf`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this :

- In Explorer, right-click any header and select "More..."
- Select "File extension"

  [image]
- Click OK.

Now you may sort on the file extension by clicking on the new
column-header.